# Some of the Javascript Stops Working When Published

Tags: jquery, publish, jquery-droppable, jquery-draggable

So as the header says, my Javascript stops working when it is published (this is on a server). (This is about Draggable/Droppable and one Droppable should only contain one Draggable).

This is my Javascript code:

```
function pageLoad() {
    $('.droppable').droppable({
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).droppable('option', 'accept', ui.draggable);
        },
        out: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).droppable('option', 'accept', '.draggable');
        },
        create: function (event, ui) {
            if ($(this).find('.draggable').length == 1) {
                $(this).droppable('option', 'accept', $(this).find('.draggable'));
            }
        },
    });

    $('.draggable').draggable({
        revert: 'invalid',
        cursor: 'move',
        zIndex: 10000
    });
}
```

Okay, so I used some of the solution from this post: [jQuery UI - Droppable only accept one draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948447/jquery-ui-droppable-only-accept-one-draggable)
There's being said: "Quick note: this only works since jQuery 1.6" – Narretz Jun 4 at 17:21. When I am running this on my published version, the JQuery doesn't work at all, none of the object is draggable.

A test I've done - Took this code out of the script:

```
drop: function (event, ui) {
    $(this).droppable('option', 'accept', ui.draggable);
},
out: function (event, ui) {
    $(this).droppable('option', 'accept', '.draggable');
},
create: function (event, ui) {
    if ($(this).find('.draggable').length == 1) {
        $(this).droppable('option', 'accept', $(this).find('.draggable'));
    }
},
```

So atleast now the Drag/Drop work in the published version, but I still want the maximum one function.

My Javascript files are referenced like this:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And my script files are in that folder, both locally and on the server.

So my suspicion falls to the "jQuery 1.6" thingy. Anybody know something about this?

Sorry for my wall of text. Thanks in beforehand

/Rickard

Comment: And you did of course include jQuery UI as well, and verified that the location is correct by checking for 404's in the network tab of the console.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @adeno: You mean my jquery-ui.min.js file?

Comment: @gpojd: There's no error when running debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Why not reference a cdn-hosted version of jQuery, so you will be using the same version on your test machine as on your server.

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Simply insert a <script> tag in your document with the src= attribute set to the link provided at the page above.  Then you're running the same version of jQuery no matter whether on a server or local. (plus this will save a small amount of server bandwidth by offloading to the CDN provider.)

Comment: Ok, I have tried it. But the Drag And drop function does still not work =/

Comment: This is really strange. How come a part of the javascript doesn't work in a published version, but in debugger mode? If I remove that little part everything is fine, but I lose functionality. So the connection to the script doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: A new experiment shows that the Drag and drop function actually works in Chrome, (not in IE where I've previously done everything). So how to get it work in IE, hm?

Comment: Found the problem, a comma too much...argh. After the create function.