# jQuery prevent droppable accepting multiple items

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable, droppable

I have the following code:

**Droppable area**

```
$( "#droppable1" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
                .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                .find( "p" )
                .html( "Dropped!" );
        }
    });

$( "#droppable1" ).on( "dropout", function( event, ui ) {
                 $( "#droppable1" )
                .removeClass("ui-state-highlight").find( "p" )
                .html( "Drop Here" );
   });
```

**Dragable item**

```
$( "#draggable1" ).draggable({ 
     snap: ".ui-widget-header", 
     snapMode: "inner", 
     axis: "y", 
     containment: "#containment-wrapper", 
     scroll: false 
});
```

All works fine BUT I cannot understand or work out how I prevent a `droppable` space from accepting multiple drops if an item has already been `dropped` into it.

1. How would I modify the code to prevent `#droppable1` from accepting
   more than one `drop`?
2. Is it possible to use the `.return` option so
       that if one tried to drop an additional item, it would merely revert
       back to its original position?

**EDIT:**

```
$(".drop-zone").droppable({
drop: function(event, ui) { 
    $(this).droppable('option', 'accept', ui.draggable);
},
out: function(event, ui){
    $(this).droppable('option', 'accept', '.drag-item');
    }   
});
```

});

The above is from the thread listed below but I am struggling to implement with my code.

**New code**

```
$( "#droppable1" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).droppable('option', 'accept', ui.draggable);
        },
        out: function(event, ui){
            $(this).droppable('option', 'accept', '.drag-item');
        }   

    });
```

OK, so I now have the code working above BUT this is actually, I don't think, what I need.  Is there any way to STOP a draggable item actually being dropped and/ or snapped on a populated droppable space?

Thanks as always,

H.

Comment: [see this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948447/jquery-ui-droppable-only-accept-one-draggable)

Comment: Thanks for the link but I'm struggling to implement that code within mine!  It seems to bready my jQuery.