# saving jquery droppable position

Tags: jquery, database, droppable

i want to save the droppable positions to a database. 
Within each droppable div ive added a text input field with the  div name with a 'i_' prefix.

If i put an alert in the code to show the dropped object, the id is correct in the alert box and appears in the text input field. But when i click the OK , it disappears.

```
<div style="float:left; border-style:solid;">
<div class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" id="1059" style="left:0px; top:0px;"    >john doe</div>
<div class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" id="1113" style="left:0px; top:0px;"    >jane doe</div>

<div   style="float:left;  vertical-align:top"  class="droppable ui-widget-header" id="1-2">
<input type='text' id='i_1-2'  name='i_1-2' value=''><p>1-2</p></div>

<div style="clear:both";></div> <div style="float:left; vertical-align:top" class="droppable ui-widget-header" id="2-1">
<input type='text' id='i_2-1'  name='i_2-1' value=''>
<p>2-1</p></div>
```

if the function that is called is this, the text box goes yellow , but the value isnt set

```
drop: function(event, ui )
                 {
            var f=ui.draggable.attr("id");alert(f);
            var s = 'i_'+$(this).attr("id");//alert(s);

              $('#'+s).css({'background-color' : 'yellow'});
              $('#'+s).val(f);

                }
```

what am i doing wrong ?

```
    $( ".droppable" ).droppable
        ({
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        drop: function( event, ui )
             {
        var f=ui.draggable.attr("id");//alert(f);
        var s = 'i_'+$(this).attr("id");
document.getElementById(s).value=f;//alert(document.getElementById(s).value);

            }

} );
```

Comment: Please show your html, otherwise, we can only guess what's wrong.

Comment: the drop function is now this. The text box goes yellow , but the value is not set

Comment: ive edited ( does it save changes automatically ?). Drag the name into the target box and the id number appears in the text box. works in the jsfiddle. Doesn't work on my machine in either FF or chrome or IE ( win7 starter)

Comment: in the browser, it stores the id in the text input if the id is surrounded with quotes ie "100" rather than 100. No other value to text manipulation gives a string or value that is stored

Comment: Did you make `$(".draggable").draggable();`? http://jsfiddle.net/93RGW/53/

Comment: Ive added the revert function .If the draggable is removed from the droppable, i want the text input field to revert to blank. Im having difficulty with code (?within draggable function) that identifies which text box I should be setting to ''

Comment: cant get the jsfiddle to save the additions.Within the draggable is this function  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735270/revert-a-jquery-draggable-object-back-to-its-original-container-on-out-event-of. I need to identify when the draggable reverts  so i can then find the input fiedl it came from and  clear it

Comment: this should help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853230/jquery-ui-draggable-event-status-on-revert

Comment: heres the latest - i can identify when the draggable is dropped in/out of a droppable. I now need to find the input box with the mtching text and delete it. My loop isnt working :-(  http://jsfiddle.net/medalto/hLQ94/34/