# JqueryUI draggable/droppable - Identify the drop target when the drop is invalid

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am using the draggable/droppable plugins of jquery-ui and i have the following scenario.

Three droppable targets (*each one accepts a single type of elements, based on class*) and multiple elements (*one of the three types that are accepted by the droppables*).

I am using the `revert` option on the draggables and the `accept` on the droppables.

Everything works normally in terms of functionality.

**What I need**: to identify the drop target when the drop is invalid (*dropped on a droppable that does not accept the dragged element*)

**What is the actual problem**: All events of droppable fire only when the dragged element is acceptable by it.

I need that information so that i can display error messages customized for the specific wrong drop-target.

I really cannot wrap my head around this problem (*besides using another drag/drop system..*), so any pointers/ideas are welcome..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up revert functions may be a good start,

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/EfeAJ/2/)**

```
$(".draggable1").draggable({
         revert: function (droppableObj) {
             //if false then no socket object drop occurred.
             if (droppableObj === false) {
                 //revert the selector object by returning true
                 alert('Not Dropped');
                 return true;
             } else {
                 //droppableObj was returned,
                 //we can perform additional checks here if we like
                 //return false so that the selector object does not revert
                 return false;
             }
         }
     });
```

For more info see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3418306/1947286
http://www.agilepro.com/blog/2009/12/while-this-functionality-is-built-into.html

Comment: yes, that is what i am leaning towards too... not using `accept` and manually checking if the droppable is valid in the `revert` callback..