# Drag and drop multiple selected cards || JQuery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have 2 columns every column has 3 cards and every card has a checkbox.
my code run as drag and drop every card alone but
i want to drag and drop multiple selected/checked cards in one movement and uncheck checkboxes when cards drop.

see [live example](https://codepen.io/yousefmohamed/pen/oNeMjpm) or snippet to live preview.

```js
$("#card-list").droppable({
  accept: $(".card").draggable({
      revert: true,
      opacity: .5
    }),
  drop: function( event, ui ){          
    var dropped = ui.draggable;
    $(this).append(dropped.clone().removeAttr('style'));
    dropped.remove();
  }
});
```

```css
.card{
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  color:#fff;
}
.right-list{
  background-color: #B91646 !important;
}
.left-list{
  background-color: #1F1D36 !important;
}
.form-check-input{
  position:absolute;
  top:0 !important;
  right:0 !important;
  left:0 !important;
  bottom:0 !important;
  margin:auto !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
    <div class="card left-list mb-3">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" aria-label="...">
      
    </div>
    <div class="card left-list mb-3">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" aria-label="...">
    </div>
    <div class="card left-list mb-3">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" aria-label="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6" id="card-list">
    <div class="card right-list mb-3">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" aria-label="...">
    </div>
    <div class="card right-list mb-3">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" aria-label="...">
    </div>
    <div class="card right-list mb-3">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" aria-label="...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function moveChecked(source, target) {
    var items = $(".card", source).filter(function(index) {
      return $("input", this).is(":checked");
    });
    items.css({
      top: "",
      left: ""
    }).appendTo(target);
    $("input", items).prop("checked", false);
  }
  
  $(".card").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    opacity: .5
  });

  $("#card-list").droppable({
    accept: ".card",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      moveChecked($(".row > .d-flex"), this);

    }
  });
});
```

```css
.card {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  color: #fff;
}

.right-list {
  background-color: #B91646 !important;
}

.left-list {
  background-color: #1F1D36 !important;
}

.form-check-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  margin: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
    <div class="card left-list mb-3">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" aria-label="...">
    </div>
    <div class="card left-list mb-3">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" aria-label="...">
    </div>
    <div class="card left-list mb-3">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" aria-label="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6" id="card-list">
    <div class="card right-list mb-3">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" aria-label="...">
    </div>
    <div class="card right-list mb-3">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" aria-label="...">
    </div>
    <div class="card right-list mb-3">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" aria-label="...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

First, you cannot use `accept` in the way you attempted. Draggable should be initialized on it's own.

I created a function yet you can do all this in the `drop` call back if you like. The function basically knows to look for Checked items and move those from the Source to the Target. It then removes any Drag styling and unchecks the items.

If you like, you can use `helper` to build an item that reflects all the checked items.

See more: https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper

**Update**

```js
$(function() {
  function hideChecked(target) {
    var items = $(".card", target).filter(function(index) {
      return $("input.form-check-input", this).is(":checked");
    });
    items.fadeOut("fast");
  }

  function moveChecked(source, target) {
    var items = $(".card", source).filter(function(index) {
      return $("input", this).is(":checked");
    });
    items.css({
      top: "",
      left: ""
    }).appendTo(target);
    $("input", items).prop("checked", false);
    items.show();
  }

  function makeHelper(event) {
    var helper = $("<div>", {
      class: "helper"
    });
    var count = $("#check-list input:checked").length;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      var offsetPos = "left+" + (i * 10) + " top+" + (i * 10);
      $("<div>", {
        class: "card left-list"
      }).html("&nbsp;").appendTo(helper).position({
        my: offsetPos,
        at: "left top",
        of: helper
      });
    }
    $(".card:last", helper).append("<input class='form-check-input' type='checkbox' checked />");
    return helper.get(0);
  }

  $("#check-list .card").draggable({
    appendTo: ".row",
    revert: function(dragObj) {
      if (dragObj === false) {
        $("#check-list .card").show();
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    },
    opacity: .5,
    helper: makeHelper,
    start: function(event, ui) {
      hideChecked($("#check-list"));
    }
  });

  $("#card-list").droppable({
    accept: ".card",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      moveChecked($(".row > .d-flex"), this);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.card {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  color: #fff;
}

.right-list {
  background-color: #B91646 !important;
}

.left-list {
  background-color: #1F1D36 !important;
}

.form-check-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  margin: auto !important;
}

.helper {
  position: relative;
}

.helper .card {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 d-flex flex-column align-items-center" id="check-list">
    <div class="card left-list mb-3">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" aria-label="...">
    </div>
    <div class="card left-list mb-3">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" aria-label="...">
    </div>
    <div class="card left-list mb-3">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" aria-label="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6" id="card-list">
    <div class="card right-list mb-3">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" aria-label="...">
    </div>
    <div class="card right-list mb-3">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" aria-label="...">
    </div>
    <div class="card right-list mb-3">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" aria-label="...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Reference: [jQuery ui.draggable event/status on revert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853230/jquery-ui-draggable-event-status-on-revert)